# Why does the bevel modifier not work?

Tags: modifiers

[image]

So I am following a tutorial and at some point I created a leg for a couch. Now I am trying to use the bevel-modifier on it, however it doesn´t seem to affect that simple form; tweaking the settings won´t work. When I use it on other objects or a cube it bevels them as it should. Can someone solve my problem?
Here´s my file https://www.dropbox.com/s/hg3lh6tbpwbp2ed/couch3.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

You have vertices overlapping, it will prevent the bevels as it will make faces overlap. Select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.

Comment: Thanks, that´s it.

Comment: @IrenäusBlaszkiewicz Don't forget to select it as the solution! :)